# Why does this draw without a background but not drawing to canvas when I setBackgroundDrawable?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable, android-canvas

When I set the background on my view.

```
//background
    Bitmap back_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background); 
    BitmapDrawable backTiled = new BitmapDrawable(back_bmp);
    backTiled.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    backTiled.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(backTiled);
```

My animated object doesn't render at all

```
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    elaine.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void update() {
    elaine.update(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

Though without the background set it draws fine.

Comment: I first tried to
backTile.draw(canvas); 
in void render but it doesn't even draw.

Answer (score 0):

I called the background in my view, and although it may have worked it really didn't work out well.

After re factoring and giving up I went back to how I thought it should work. I should have check if something that didn't work(Only because when I first tried it the code didn't set boundaries or load image efficiently.) might work again.

I did and realized that everything works perfectly if loaded within render.

```
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    //background
    Bitmap _back_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.background); 
    backTiled = new BitmapDrawable(_back_bmp);
    backTiled.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    backTiled.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    backTiled.draw(canvas);
    elaine.draw(canvas);

    }
```

Comment: Note that if you're decoding your bitmap and creating a Drawable for it every time you draw, you're going to end up with some performance issues (lots of new object creation resulting in frequent garbage collection and possibly OutOfMemoryExceptions). Drawing the background before drawing on top of it is the right strategy though.

Comment: @kabuko Should I initialize _back_bmp and backTiled somewhere else? Would placing it surfaceCreated clear this up?

Comment: Yeah, putting it in surfaceCreated should fix most of those issues. You could even consider putting it at an even "higher" level perhaps in the SurfaceView constructor.

Comment: I took your advice, and put it in surfaceCreated. It works perfectly. When I place it in the SurfaceView for some reason it doesn't draw though it compiles.